# Why to use scan.nextLine(); to scan a string along with integers

Tags: java

Hi I got an issue and solved but I don't know the reason:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "Hello ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    String c;
    a= scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    c = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(i + a);
    System.out.println(s + c);
    scan.close();
    }
}
input:
4
World! How are you!!
```

When I remove the line `scan.nextLine();` before `c = scan.nextLine();` I get an error. Could anyone suggest me the reason.

I used:

```
String a;
String c;
a = scan.nextLine();
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(i + a);
System.out.println(s + c);
```

but getting answer as :

```
44
Hello World! How are you
```

Comment: What error? What did you try to do with it?

Comment: `nextInt()` doesn't consume new line character. I would recommend always getting user input with `nextLine()` and then parsing, e.g. `Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())`.

Comment: I did as you suggested but still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

scan.nextLine is reading the enter key after your input of 4.

Without it c is set to the enter key and your program completes.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 4;
    String s = "Hello ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    String c;
    a = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    c = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(i + a);
    System.out.println(s + c);
    scan.close();
}
```

With inputs of "4" and Doug the output is:

```
8
Hello Doug
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your original code

```
scan.nextLine();
a = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(i + a);
System.out.println(s + c);
```

is the first line. You essentiall discard the first line of input.

Consider your input

> 4
>   How are you

The first line is read by your first

```
scan.nextLine();
```

Thus, the first line

> 4

is discarded.

Then, the next line of code is

```
a = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

which first executes `scan.nextLine()`. This reads your second line

> How are you

And tries to convert it into a number using `Integer.parseInt()`, which fails with your exception.

---

In your solution

```
a= scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
c = scan.nextLine();
```

the second line is necessary, because `scan.nextInt` does not remove the newline.

Consider again the input

> 4
>   How are you

The first line `a = scan.nextInt();` reads the

> 4

and only the `4`, leaving the input as

> How are you

If you would now execute `c = scan.nextLine();` directly, `c` would be assigned the empty string, which is still the first line.
Thus, the second line removes the empty line, and leaves the input as

> How are you

which can now be read with `c = scan.nextLine();` to get the desired string.

---

If you have more question, try to simulate an execution your code, both by the debugger and by hand, maybe even on paper. This helps you understanding what actually is happening.

Answer (score -1):

if you delete the line `scan.nextLine();` ,it means you input two datas in one line(variable a and c). it is hard for compiler to decide which one should be solved.But if you add the line `scan.nextLine();`,two inputs will be compiled in different lines and will be OK.